# Minimal graded free resolution of the ideal $(x^3,xy^2,y^5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am looking for a detailed explanation of every step of the construction of a graded free resolution of the ideal $(x^3,xy^2,y^5) \subseteq S=K[x,y]$ where $K$ is an arbitrary field.

I saw several examples of such resolutions, but without any explanation; I saw that sometimes such a resolution depends on the characteristic of the field, so let's start supposing that $K= \mathbb{C}$.

I know how to start the algorithm but I get stuck in the second step:
I start with the surjection
$$S(-3)\oplus S(-3)\oplus S(-5)\stackrel{f}\longrightarrow I \longrightarrow 0,$$
such that
$$e_1\mapsto x^3,\qquad e_2\mapsto xy^2,\qquad e_3\mapsto y^5.$$

I know that $$\ker (f)=\langle y^2e_1-x^2e_2, y^3e_2-xe_3\rangle.$$

But how do I proceed now? I think I should find homogeneous generators for $\ker(f)$, but I am not even sure what "homogeneous" means in this context.

Could you please enlighten me? Thank you very much.

Asdrubale

Comment: How did you find ker(f)? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You have already found all the relations! What you need to do is just to write them. To ensure that you have found them all, you can use the Hilbert Syzygy theorem which says the length of the minimal graded free resolution can be at most 2. Let $I = (x^3, xy^2, y^3)$. Then the resolution of $S/I$ is 
$$
0 \to S^k \to S^3 \to S \to S/I \to 0.
$$
But simple computation of rank of the modules, you can see that $k = 2$. 
The only thing that remains is determining the grade shift. But your computation already shows that 
$$
\phi: S(-5) \oplus S(-6) \to S(-3) \oplus S(-3) \oplus S(-5),
$$
where the map $\phi$ is the 3 by 2 matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y^2 & 0\\
x^2 & y^3 \\
0 & -x
\end{bmatrix}.
$$